# Can I apply Fundamental Theorem of Calculus here?

Tags: calculus, integration

Something tells me I can't, but I also feel I can because the integral is going to be messy if I integrate directly with trig substitution.

The integral comes from a physics problem I am doing.

$$V(x) = k\lambda\int_{0}^{a} \dfrac{ d\ell}{\sqrt{x^2 + \ell ^2}}$$

$a$ is a constant, but I can let change $a$ to a variable like $h$

I am trying to find $-\dfrac{dV}{dx}$

The only thing that's bothering me is that x inside the integrand and setting $\ell = x$ after I apply chain rule would get me a $\sqrt{2}$ and I don't think the answer is going to come out this nice.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No, you can't do it like that."

The fundamental theorem of calculus would read as follows. Let
$$
F(a)=-k\lambda\int_{\ell=0}^a\frac{d\ell}{\sqrt{x^2+\ell^2}}.
$$
Then FTC tells that
$$
\frac{dF}{da}=-k\lambda\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}.
$$
In other words, your mistake was about mixing the roles of different variables. In its basic form FTC allows you to differentiate a function of **the variable appearing as the upper limit** (here $a$) by substituting its value at a given point **in place of the variable of integration** (here $\ell$). In your example the variable $x$ is in neither of those roles, so it should be treated as a parameter as in André's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will find everything you need [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) about differentiating under the integral sign. The article also deals with situations in which the limits of integration are not constant.

The derivative $\frac{dV}{dx}$ is equal to the integral from $0$ to $a$ of the partial derivative (with respect to $x$) of your function.  In our case we get
$$\frac{dV}{dx}=-k\lambda\int_0^a \frac{x}{(x^2+\ell^2)^{3/2}}d\ell.$$
The integration can be done, for example, by letting $\ell=x\tan\theta$.  You end up needing to integrate $\cos\theta$, which is easy. Or else one can use $\ell=x\sinh t$.

In this case, the original integral can be calculated explicitly, and then we can differentiate.  However, if we use a trigonometric substitution, we end up integrating $\sec\theta$, which is not as pleasant. A $\sinh$ substitution is nicer.

One could also treat $a$ as a variable, and differentiate. That part is easy, but in order to find $\frac{dV}{dx}$, an integration is still needed at the end.

Comment: I am actually trying to avoid any trig substitution.

Comment: You can avoid trig substitution by using hyperbolic sine. There is also a somewhat messier integration by parts approach.

Comment: No no no. I mean no integration at all. Is it possible? Because I want to take the derivative in the end anyways.

Comment: By taking the derivative at the end, do you mean with respect to $x$, as in your problem? The integral is with respect to a different variable. In general one cannot avoid it.

Comment: @jak: So you are asking for an answer to an integration problem, which exploits completely not of integrals? Hmm, interesting thought...